# PagedList is growing but never shrinking in Android app using Room

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In my Android app i have a very basic `RecyclerView` implementation that shows entries from a database using [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) with the [Paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/).

The Dao method that fetches entries from the database:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM entries")
abstract fun findAll(): DataSource.Factory<Int, Entry>
```

And this is how `LiveData` is constructed from the returned `DataSource.Factory` in my `ViewModel`:

```
private val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
        .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
        .setInitialLoadSizeHint(512)
        .setPrefetchDistance(256)
        .setPageSize(256)
        .build()

val entries = LivePagedListBuilder(entryService.findAll(), config).build()
// (entryService here just calls through to the Dao)
```

I simply observe on this `LiveData` and pass the updated `PagedList` to my `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

The corresponding `RecyclerView.Adapter` snippet:

```
private val differ = AsyncPagedListDiffer<Entry>(this, DIFF_CALLBACK)

fun submitList(list: PagedList<Entry>) {
    differ.submitList(list)
}
```

(i do not use `PagedListAdapter`, because i'll need more fine-grained control in my adapter later)

Seemingly everything works fine, but when i started monitor memory usage of the app, i started to suspect that the `PagedList` items are not handled properly.

I've added the following `Callback` in `submitList()`:

```
list.addWeakCallback(differ.currentList?.snapshot(), object : PagedList.Callback() {
    override fun onChanged(position: Int, count: Int) {
        Log.d("_tag", "Position: $position | Changed: $count" +
                " | Size: ${list.size}")
    }

    override fun onInserted(position: Int, count: Int) {
        Log.d("_tag", "Position: $position | Inserted: $count" +
                " | Size: ${list.size}")
    }

    override fun onRemoved(position: Int, count: Int) {
        Log.d("_tag", "Position: $position | Removed: $count" +
                " | Size: ${list.size}")
    }
})
```

After this i've inserted 5 000 entries into the database and the corresponding log entry was the following:

> D/_tag: Position: 0 | Inserted: 512 | Size: 512

This is fine, this is the expected output.

But as i start scrolling down in the list, the log entries are as follows:

> D/_tag: Position: 512 | Inserted: 256 | Size: 768
>
> D/_tag: Position: 768 | Inserted: 256 | Size: 1024
>
> D/_tag: Position: 1024 | Inserted: 256 | Size: 1280
>
> D/_tag: Position: 1280 | Inserted: 256 | Size: 1536

And then the logs stop here, no more log entries, no matter how much i scroll down after this point.

My questions regarding this behavior:

- Why `onRemoved()` is never called?

  Is `PagedList` an ever-growing list and the items stay in the memory?

  Isn't the point of paging is to load new entries on demand **and remove** old (not visible) ones as well?
- Why do the logs stop after the 1536th entry, even if i scroll way past that entry?

  The strange thing is, the entries are displayed properly, even if a scroll all the way to the bottom of the list.

I'd really appreciate if someone could explain the behavior to me.

(Java answers are welcome as well)

**EDIT**:

The code of the whole adapter:

```
class EntryListAdapter
        : RecyclerView.Adapter<EntryListAdapter.EntryViewHolder>() {

    private val differ = AsyncPagedListDiffer<Entry>(this, DIFF_CALLBACK)

    fun submitList(list: PagedList<Entry>) {
        differ.submitList(list)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int):
            EntryViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val entryItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_entry, parent, false)

        return EntryViewHolder(entryItemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: EntryViewHolder, position: Int) {
        differ.getItem(position)?.let { holder.bindTo(it) }
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return differ.getItem(position)?.id ?: RecyclerView.NO_ID
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return differ.currentList?.size ?: 0
    }

    inner class EntryViewHolder(itemView: View) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bindTo(entry: Entry) {
            itemView.textEntryTitle.text = entry.title
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val DIFF_CALLBACK = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Entry>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(entry1: Entry, entry2: Entry): Boolean {
                return entry1.id == entry2.id
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(entry1: Entry, entry2: Entry): Boolean
            {
                return entry1 == entry2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**:

The layout of the `Fragment` that hosts the `RecyclerView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/mainRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris Craik of the Android Architecture Components teams has just confirmed on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/9luvhs/is_the_paging_library_still_not_able_to_drop_data/e7b6loy) that as of yet the Paging library do not drop paged data (but it's coming):

> It is merged ([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/e8ca38c168166586980e51a0a6bf7ca9aa3a5b40) and [2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/51eaeb259cb8a4f6a31f2926760decdbdf6c256c)), but we haven't released it yet due to being
>   extra-careful during the AndroidX switchover. Arch had to be careful
>   to avoid causing regressions during an AndroidX migration (since those
>   migrations are complex enough).
>
> Now that AndroidX is stable, we can do the release, so we'll see about
>   having it out soon.

Comment: I'm using AndroidX, but I don't think the issue is solved.